# Exclude folder from sync

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync, ubuntu-one-windows

I have several subdirectories in my ubuntuone directory (docs, photos, music) and installed ubuntuone on several devices (laptop, pc, ...).

I want my docs and photos to be synced with all the connected devices (especially docs), but I want to exclude the music directory. It's huge, and I don't want a copy of this directory on every device. Is there a way to achieve this (with both Ubuntu and Windows devices)?

It's in the ubuntuone directory, so that I access it with Ubuntu One Music.

Comment: I already found a solution...
By placing the music dir outside my ubuntuone dir, and share it separately, I can enable/disable syncing to this dir on every device.

Comment: Please do add your solution as an answer to your question and accept it :)

Answer (score 2):

(community wiki - converted OP comment to answer)

One solution I found

By placing the music folder outside my ubuntuone folder, you can share it separately.

You can enable/disable syncing to this folder on every device.